# Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex' when using mk4ht

Tags: pdftex, conversion, moderncv, msword

I am trying to convert TeX, made using `moderncv`, to `.doc` format. I am trying to use the following 2 commands

```
pdflatex filename.tex
mk4ht oolatex filename.tex
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3905 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

How can I fix the problem? If it is not possible is there any alternate way to convert TeX to `.doc`?

Comment: Don't put the `pdftex` option when calling **hyperref**; it's not necessary even when using `pdflatex`.

Comment: @egreg: I think `moderncv` does this itself!

Comment: It's a misfeature of the class, then.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I am using Latex as a compiler inside the Overleaf, and I fixed this error by removing **pdftex**. Instead of `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}`, use `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Answer (score 9):

tex4ht uses dvi as the intermediate format (it inserts `\special`s into the dvi file).  Therefore it internally calls latex, *not* pdflatex.

Since moderncv uses hyperref as pdftex option, you might want to override it in the document, adding before teh4ht run:

```
\hypersetup{tex4ht}
```

You can do it automatically using this tex4ht magic that determines whether tex4ht is used:

```
\ifx\HCode\UnDef\else\hypersetup{tex4ht}\fi
```

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid, but how can I use it? I'm a newbie to latex. I tried copy pasting it in the tex but I'm getting the error

 ! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \ifx\HCode\UnDef\else\hypersetup
                                    {tex4ht}\fi

Comment: can you please post an example?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\ifx\HCode\UnDef\else\hypersetup{tex4ht}\fi             
\moderncvtheme[blue,roman]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Comment: Well, this works for me.  I am afraid you need to post a complete example.

Comment: Oh sorry this is when running mk4ht oolatex filename.tex

Comment: it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of `moderncv`, there is certainly the `pdftex` option set when requiring (importing) `hyperref`. It seems to be fixed in the latest distribution; sadly, this doesn't seem to have made its way to OpenSuSE yet.