# problem with macro using \ifx

Tags: macros, hyperref, fontspec, tex4ht

[Edit 1] originally titled "can't understand why this simple macro causes complex error"

[original post] I've written a book, and now I'm trying to produce the e-book using tex4ht.  Adapting [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/package-hyperref-error-wrong-driver-option-pdftex-when-using-mk4ht), I introduced the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\gpifpdf}[2]{\ifx\HCode\UnDef{#1}\else{#2}\fi}
```

Which should return the first argument when producing the pdf file, and the second when using mk4ht to produce the html file.

Here is my m(n)we:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\gpifpdf}[2]{\ifx\HCode\UnDef{#1}\else{#2}\fi}
\gpifpdf{
  \usepackage{fontspec}
}{
  \hypersetup{tex4ht}
}
\begin{document}
\gpifpdf{this is pdf text}{this is HTML text}
\end{document}
```

mk4ht produces an html file which displays "this is HTML text."  But using Latexian to generate a pdf generates the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\clist_if_empty:NF #1->\if_meaning:w 
                                 #1\c_empty_tl \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi: \c_zero {}
l.9 \begin{document}
```

HOWEVER, when I comment out `\usepackage{fontspec}`, it works perfectly, producing a pdf reading "this is pdf text," so the macro seems to work correctly in the document body.  When I leave in the `\usepackage{fontspec}`, and comment out the line before and the 3 lines afterwards (lines 4, 6, 7, and 8) it also produces the pdf just fine.

In other words: the macro seems to function correctly, and when I do what the macro is supposed to do by hand, everything works, but when I try to get the macro to do it, it doesn't.

I just upgrade to MacTeX 2014 from 2013 (so TeXlive 2014), and the problem continues.  I am using Latexian, with the XeTeX option.

Comment: Aren't the braces aroun `{#1}` and `{#2}` acting as a group? You can remove them.

Comment: You might want to change the title to a better one that explains your problem (`\ifx`) which could be good for future users that need to search for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Manuel, changed the title as suggested, hope that is clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is not

```
\ifx<firsttoken><secondtoken>{<true code>}\else{<false code>}\fi
```

The correct one is

```
\ifx<firsttoken><secondtoken><true code>\else<false code>\fi
```

So you can remove the braces around `{#1}` and `{#2}` (which, in the case of `\usepackage{fontspec}` act as a group delimiter).